# Is there a quick way of adding captcha in pyrocms contact form?

Tags: pyrocms

I am working on a very simple contact form, by modifiying default contact form of pyrocsms standard installation. I have looks at the documentation about adding captcha, but seems to not find any clear way of adding it. Is there a plugin/addons that simplify adding captcha in PyroCMS? Or, I should go deeper into CodeIgniter captcha helper, as shown here : [CAPTCHA Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We had a captcha in there ages ago but the clear opinion of the community was that it was a pain in the ass and more people were against it being there than were for.

Instead we implemented Akismet, so you can just use that instead. That way they check if its spam for you, instead of pestering your users so hard they dont even bother submitting the form.

Comment: I've manage to implement recaptcha in my application. Haven't test askimet for this. Thanks @phil!

Comment: @swdev could you provide an example of how did you do this? I have found `agustindidiego/recaptcha-extension` on github but it displays only a field in the form without additing scripts in head and doesn't adds event listeners to submit button. Thanks